# PHP and VB.net - same database

Tags: php, mysql, vb.net, visual-studio

i have a PHP website and i want to have a windows application for that 
so that users registered in the website can login easily in the windows application (Visual Basic .net )

what way do you suggest for having a single database that both PHP and VB.net can easily connect to?

Comment: yes. What is the problem with that ?

Answer (score 3):

you can just have a database in MYSQL (or other) and create a webservice ([SOAP WS for sample](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.soap.php)) for your VB Application.

One Database for php and VB application :)

Comment: i don't know what a webservice is and how to use it  :(

Comment: I think read this SOAP [tutorial](http://phpmaster.com/web-services-with-php-and-soap-1/) for PHP after, you know what is webservices, and you want to create this in PHP.  

After create this, You want test your WebServices request with [SOAPUI](http://www.soapui.org/) it's SOAP client.

After, just integrate call request in your vb application.

Comment: ok i read the article and created the file in my host. but i don't know how to send requests from vb.net to the server :( 
i have seen examples but i understood nothing ... :">

Comment: Hi, [here](http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/868113-soap-request-using-vb-net) this a forum chanel, there speak for create a SOAP request in Visual Basic. Don't forget : Google is your friend :-)

Answer (score 2):

I would create a webservices layer between the two. You should never allow the user's application to connect directly to your database because that makes it ridiculously easy for a malicious user to do any arbitrary query against your DB.

What I would do is provide a webservice that accepts post parameters for username/password then returns an authentication token that the client uses in subsequent requests. I'd then develop a variety of other services that handle the interactions for the client.

Comment: so the webservice only returns an authentication token ?
what if the user is able to add or change values in the database ? ie. adding values to his table ...

Comment: @ArmanJelodar See second paragraph, "I'd then develop a variety of other services that handle interactions for the client" you'd use the token from the first service with the other services that are "the other interactions" such as create/update/delete.

Comment: will you explain for me how to create a webservice and how to do this  ? thank you very much :)

Comment: @ArmanJelodar A webservice can be anything from a service that uses something like http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/ (NuSoap) to just a PHP file that accepts POST parameters and returns a result using JSON encode. There's not much to it.

Answer (score 0):

Any serious database.

If you happen upon a database that prefers a certain language, move on to the next.

To name a few popular choices: mySQL, Postgres, MSSQL, SQLite. AVoid access.

Answer (score -3):

I would suggest to use a MYSQL Database. With PHP it's really easy to connect to a MYSQL database. And using VB.net you can connect to the same database that PHP is using. This must not be very difficult using ADO.